# replace more than one pattern python

Tags: python, regex, twitter

I have reviewed various links but all showed how to replace multiple words in one pass. However, instead of words I want to replace patterns e.g.

> RT @amrightnow: "The Real Trump" Trump About You" Watch Make #1
>   https:\/\/t.co\/j58e8aacrE #tcot #pjnet #1A #2A #Tru mp #trump2016
>   https:\/\/t.co\u2026

When I perform the following two commands on the above text I get the desired output

```
result = re.sub(r"http\S+","",sent)
result1 = re.sub(r"@\S+","",result)
```

This way I am removing all the urls and @(handlers from the tweet). The output will be something like follows:

```
>>> result1
'RT  "The Real Trump" Trump About You" Watch Make #1  #tcot #pjnet #1A #2A #Trump #trump2016 '
```

Could someone let me know what is the best way to do it? I will be basically reading tweets from a file. I want to read each tweet and replace these handlers and urls with blanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the regex "or" operator which is the pipe `|`:

```
re.sub(r"http\S+|@\S+","",sent)
```

If you have a long list of patterns that you want to remove, a common trick is to use `join` to create the regular expression:

```
to_match = ['http\S+',
            '@\S+',
            'something_else_you_might_want_to_remove']

re.sub('|'.join(to_match), '', sent)
```

Comment: was going thru the documentation and I got the following "A|B, where A and B can be arbitrary REs, creates a regular expression that will match either A or B. An arbitrary number of REs can be separated by the '|' in this way. This can be used inside groups (see below) as well. As the target string is scanned, REs separated by '|' are tried from left to right. When one pattern completely matches, that branch is accepted. This means that once A matches, B will not be tested further, even if it would produce a longer overall match" hence I did not use it. This document is confusing me

Comment: yeah that doesn't make sense to me either, all i know is that this is the way you do it.

Comment: regex's can overlap. For example, `re.sub(r'ab|abc', '', 'abc')` returns `'c'`. The left-most regex matched `'ab'` so it won. The upshot is that you have to consider the order you write them in. In this case, there is some potential overlap (e.g., the first regex would match `'http@something'`) but I think it still fits what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an "or" pattern by separating the patterns with `|`:

```
import re

s = u'RT @amrightnow: "The Real Trump" Trump About You" Watch Make #1 https:\/\/t.co\/j58e8aacrE #tcot #pjnet #1A #2A #Tru mp #trump2016 https:\/\/t.co\u2026'
result = re.sub(r"http\S+|@\S+", "", s)
print result
```

**Output**

```
RT  "The Real Trump" Trump About You" Watch Make #1  #tcot #pjnet #1A #2A #Tru mp #trump2016
```

See the subsection `'|'` in the [regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) documentation.

Comment: somebody beat you to it!

Comment: @tdelaney: yes, they did. They're basically the same answer, although mine shows a full working example.

Comment: @mhawke as I have noted above the documentation confused me saying that once A passes it does not look at B.. what is that about??

Comment: @user1122534 It means that if your pattern is `'foo|bar|barbaz'` and the string is, say, `'barbaz'`, the pattern will match `bar` (because it first tries `foo`, no match, then `bar`, matched) and will not match the longer `barbaz` (because it stops trying  as soon as a match is found).